# Ayuda con detalles y cantidad en php

Tags: php, html

> Mi problema es que al elegir el item 1 al querer agregar el mismo item, me suma bien la cantidad , pero agrego el segundo item y al agregar me suma pero con la cantidad del item 1 . Me pueden ayudar en esa parte por favor.

[image: Mi modal en el detalle]

> Codigo

```
include '../models/pedido.model.php';
$conexion = new Pedidos();

if (!isset($_POST['id'])) {
    header('Location: pedido.vista.php');
}

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
    $item = $_POST['item'];
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];

    $consulta = $conexion->getDetalles($id,$cliente,$item);
    $reg = $consulta->fetch_array();





    if (!empty($reg))       {


        $consultaverificacion = $conexion->getDetallesItem($id,$cliente,$item);
        $resverificacion = $consultaverificacion->fetch_array();
        if ($resverificacion>0) {

            $cant_new = ($reg['cantidad']+$cantidad);
            $conexion->updateDetalle($reg['idpedidocliente'],$reg['idcliente'],$reg['iditem'],$cant_new);
            $res = $conexion->getExistencia($item);
            $var = $res->fetch_array();
            $existencia = ($cantidad*1000)+$var['0'];
            $conexion->updateExistencia($item,$existencia);
            //en caso de que el item ya haya sido añadido previamente

            $res = $conexion->getExistencia($item);
            $var = $res->fetch_array();
            $existencia = ($cantidad*1000)+$var['0'];
            $conexion->updateExistencia($item,$existencia);

        } else {
            //en caso de que el item aun no haya sido añadido
            $conexion->addDetalle($id,$cliente,$item,$cantidad);
        }



    }       else        {
        $conexion->addDetalle($id,$cliente,$item,$cantidad);


    }
```

> archivo modelo , updateExistencia

```
    public function updateExistencia($id,$v0)
{
    //crear statement
    $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('UPDATE items SET iditem = ?');
    //parametro a statement
    $stmt->bind_param('ii',$v0,$id);
    //ejecutar el query
    $stmt->execute();
    //cerrar statement
    $stmt->close();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es decir que estás agregando a la lista un 'TOSIBA' de cantidad 1 y el problema es que lo está agregando a 'ACER PC' ?, si es así verifica el valor del dropdown(item) y la query del UPDATE.

Comment: Si agrego un toshiba cantidad 1 o la cantidad que necesite, con el primer item no tengo problemas, pero al agregar acer , me agrega cantidad 1, si agrego 1 acer mas, me suma cantidad de acer con la cantidad de toshiba. Osea siempre me suma con la cantidad del primer item.

Comment: es probable que esta consulta:
`$consulta = $conexion->getDetalles($id,$cliente,$item);
$reg = $consulta->fetch_array();`
este retornando siempre la primera fila

Comment: Tenias razón , tenia mal nombre de getDetalles jaja que tonto soy , Muchas Gracias.!!